# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread.models'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, gspread

I´m using **gspread** in Colab and upgraded it to enable the set_timeout option, but now using **gspread_dataframe** gives the error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread.models'**
Thanks in advance.
my Code:

```
#!pip install gspread --upgrade
#!pip install gspread-dataframe
#!pip install openpyxl

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
#from gspread_formatting.dataframe import format_with_dataframe

gspread.__version__
5.2.0
```

Comment: Provide a full stacktrace

Answer (score 4):

Solved!

---

```
!pip uninstall gspread-dataframe
    
Successfully uninstalled gspread-dataframe-3.0.8


pip install gspread-dataframe

Successfully installed gspread-dataframe-3.2.2
***
```

Comment: It works but could have simply upgrade gspread-dataframe using "pip install -U gspread-dataframe"

Answer (score 3):

For those using `gspread` directly this error is because in 5.x versions of gspread you should use:

```
from gspread import Worksheet
```

instead of

```
from gspread.models import Worksheet
```